# ITextSharp throws NullReference exception at enddocument

Tags: c#, itext

I have a code of :

```
  TextReader reader = new StringReader(html);// step 1: creation of a document-object
  var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30, 30, 30, 30);
  var resultPdf = new MemoryStream();
  PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, resultPdf);
  var worker = new HTMLWorker(document);
  document.Open();
  FontFactory.Register(FontFileName, "arial unicode ms");
  var st = new StyleSheet();
  st.LoadTagStyle("body", "encoding", "Identity-H");
  worker.Style = st;
  worker.StartDocument();
  worker.Parse(reader);
  worker.EndDocument();
  worker.Close();
  document.Close();
```

That code fails at line:

```
  worker.EndDocument();
```

With exception of:

```
  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  at iTextSharp.text.FontFactoryImp.GetFont(String fontname, String encoding, Boolean embedded, Single size, Int32 style, BaseColor color, Boolean cached)
  at iTextSharp.text.FontFactoryImp.GetFont(String fontname, String encoding, Boolean embedded, Single size, Int32 style, BaseColor color)
  at iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.FactoryProperties.GetFont(ChainedProperties props)
  at iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.FactoryProperties.CreateChunk(String text, ChainedProperties props)
  at iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.Text(String str)
  at iTextSharp.text.xml.simpleparser.SimpleXMLParser.Flush()
  at iTextSharp.text.xml.simpleparser.SimpleXMLParser.Go(TextReader reader)
```

My html using

```
  <div style="font-family: arial unicode ms">
  <div style="padding-left: 15px;">
```

Unfortunately it is not raised in 100%.

Has someone seen it before?
Thanks

Comment: Just to guess the obvious, you've verified that `System.IO.File.Exists(pathToFont + "\\" + _fontName)`, right? `FontFactory.Register()` doesn't fail on invalid font paths but the parser later on might when it goes to dereference the name.

Comment: thank you, yes, file exists, that part of code is run 1000 times per day, and some time it fails as in log, sometime - succeeded

Comment: What version of iTextSharp are you using?

Comment: hi, thanks - my version is 5.0.5.0

Comment: seems the reason was old simple multithreading - as soon as we have replace FontFactory.Register(FontFileName, "arial unicode ms"); with if (FontFactory.IsRegistered(ARIAL_UNI_MS_FONT)) ... we don't see these errors